# How to replace string in the website after PHP have complete the processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search, replace

For example , the is a word 'cat', and I would like to change to 'dog' in every page,

but in server side:

```
 str_replace("cat","dog",$doc);
```

or in cilent side:

```
 doc.replace("cat", "dog");
```

I need to provide the doc variable, is it possible to just auto search and find the server processed result and replace the word in every page?

It may also changed the code in javascript and lead to error , but to simplify , just assume the jquery doesn't have function name/ variable using 'cat'

Thanks a lot for helping.

**Updated:**

Thanks for the answer. Last question, if I use framework such as codeigniter, where should I put the ob buffer code?

e.g.

In controller?

```
function index() {
    $data['demo_data'] = $demo_data;
    $this->load->view('test',$data);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question? What is the issue exactly?

Comment: @user782104 i've written about codeigniter in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's all meaningless, but it works

```
 document.documentElement.innerHTML = 
 document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/cat/g,'dog')
```

About codeigniter

```
function index() {
    $data['demo_data'] = $demo_data;
    //  Add 3rd argument as true to get output muffer
    $text = $this->load->view('test',$data, true);
    // Any manipulations with text
    echo $text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. can I globally apply to view, as there are hunderds of controller and apply view function

Comment: @user782104 Yes. you can declare hook and do that. It's probably more correct way. for example, look there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690251/codeigniter-how-to-modify-buffered-output-before-sending

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is tu use output buffering :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php (see Example #1)

You have to be careful  when to replace text in html because str_replace() will also match in html tags and javascript code in your page.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution would be to use a variable:

```
<?php
$animal = 'cat';

echo "My $animal took a walk in the park.".
```

The methods you suggest both imply a bad design and will possibly result in undesirable side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use output buffering in PHP. 
http://php.net/ob_start

```
<?php
ob_start();

//do some stuff

$buffer = ob_get_flush();
$output = preg_replace(/\bcat\b/, 'dog', $buffer);
echo $out;
```